# Finding chars in a string using Hash table

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, hashtable

I decided to solve the problem of finding given characters in a string. And I solved it in two ways:

The first(using hash-table to keep the values in ASCII for the chars we want to find):

```
static void Hash(string text, char[] charsToFind)
{
    Dictionary<int,char> chars = new Dictionary<int,char>();
    foreach (var letter in charsToFind)
    {
        chars[(int)letter] = letter;
    }

    foreach (var letter in text)
    {
        if (chars.ContainsKey((int)letter))
        {
            if (letter == chars[(int)letter])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Element found at: {0}, value: {1}", (int)letter, letter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the second way (the naive):

```
static void Naive(string text, char[] charsToFind)
{
    foreach (var letter in text)
    {
        foreach (var character in charsToFind)
        {
            if ((int)letter == (int)character)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Element found at: {0}, value: {1}", (int)letter, letter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And everything works fine! The question I'd like to ask is which one is the better and if there are even better solutions to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does limitation "only .NET 2.0" exist or you're free to use 3.5 or 4.0?

Comment: you can use every version od .NET

Comment: Your first method is wrong. It should be a Dict<char,int> and you should populate it with `for(int i = text.Length - 1; i > -1; i--) chars[text[i]] = text[i];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
string input = "abc";
char[] charsToFind = new[] { 'a', '1', 'b' };
IEnumerable<int> ids = charsToFind.Select(ch => input.IndexOf(ch)); // { 0, -1, 1 }
```

---

With `Hashset<T>` which is generic hash table:

```
HashSet<char> set = new HashSet<char>(input.ToCharArray());
...
```

Comment: Thanks! But is my algorithm with the hash table more efficient and better?

Comment: +1. .@Tsvetan, you can probably take sample inputs and check execution time.

Comment: I know, but I'm asking about which one is the better in terms of programming practise.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is a better approach, but the second one will probably be faster for a small number of characters.

Some comments on the first one. 
In the first one, using a dictionary involves cost of calculating the hash and performing a lookup. If you knew the chars were ASCII, you could use an array to speed up the lookup.

Rather than doing a 'ContainsKey' you could do a 'TryGetValue' to only lookup once.

Comment: I know the characters were ASCII, but I read that using hash-table was a better approach. So, I decided to ask here...

Comment: Yes, but the hash table is slower as it needs to do more work.

Comment: The interesting thing I found is that the naive algorithm is the fastest(~0010000ms). Then its the hash and after that the LINQ. The tests were made on 30,7KB of text. I'll try your approach too and will see what will happen...